# Changing order of integration, bound is a function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the following double integral:
$$\int_{g(v)}^v \int_{g(z)}^z f(z,y)\mathrm{d} y \mathrm{d} z$$

I need to change the order of integration to $\mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}y$.

$g$ is some increasing function that is below the $45°$-line.

1) Is it correct that, if $g(x) = 0 \space\forall \space x$, then the the double integral above could be rewritten as
$$\int_{0}^v \int_{0}^z f(z,y) \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{d} z = \int_{0}^v \int_{y}^v f(z,y) \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} y\: ?$$

2) If this was correct, i don't know how to do the trick for another $g$ function. Say $g(x)= \cfrac{x}{2}$. Then the integration area should be this [image: integration area in red]

If I now want to integrate with respect to z first, the bounds should be 
$$g(v) < z < v.$$
But then the upper and lower level in the y dimension depend on $z$.
Is it necessary to slice the area into two (in this particular case $g(x)= \frac{x}{2}$) triangles?

Comment: Why is $z$ an integration variable and a limit?

Comment: Because the integration limit of the inner integral depends on the outer integration variable.

Comment: Of course, sorry, my mistake

Comment: So the limit varies with z, as in the graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(z)\leq y\leq z$, $g(v)\leq z\leq v$. $g$ is increasing so you can certainly use its inverse $g^{-1}$. $g(z)\leq y$ means $z\leq g^{-1}(y)$. Combining with $y\leq z$, we get:
$$y\leq z\leq g^{-1}(y).$$
We know $y\leq z\leq v$, so $y\leq v$. We know $g(v)\leq z$, so $v\leq g^{-1}(z)$. But $z\leq g^{-1}(y)$ so $g^{-1}(z)\leq g^{-2}(y)$, so $v\leq g^{-2}(y)$ or $g(g(v))\leq y$. In other words:
$$g(g(v))\leq y\leq v.$$
That should give the bounds for the inversion.

**Edit**

It seems that, at least in some cases (e.g. that presented in comments), the integration domain obtained with these new inequalities is strictly bigger than the one of the old ones. I think this might be because those new inequalities do not imply $g(v)\leq z\leq v$ directly. At least, in the case of comments this was the problem. So integrating in $z$ from $\max\{g(v),y\}$ to $\min\{v,g^{-1}(y)\}$ should fix the problem in at least some cases (e.g. that of comments).

Comment: I don't see any flaw in your logic so far. But consider the examplary region I drew and take f(x,y)=1, g(x) = x/2 and v=8.
Then "my" integral yields 12 and yours yields 30.
The integration area seems to differ when I draw it, too.

Comment: $\int_4^8 \int_{z/2}^z 1 dy d z = \int_4^8 z/2 d z = 12$ and
$\int_2^8 \int_{y}^2y 1 dz d y = \int_2^8 y d z = 30$
No?

Comment: Indeed: [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lYqt0.jpg) we have the new region with continuous boundary and the old one with dotted ones. Seems like $\mathrm{old}\subsetneqq\mathrm{new}$, so I must need some other inequality for the bounds.

Comment: But your comment was missing some braces: you meant $\int_2^8\int_y^{2y}1dzdy$, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, indeed, the braces are missing.

Comment: Seeing this region, it seems the inner integral should be $\int_{\max\{4,y\}}^{\min\{8,2y\}}$. That is, $\int_{\max\{g(v),y)\}}^{\min\{v,g^{-1}(y)\}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness. I accepted the answer by MickG.

To get the area drawn in the original post, I took the area of the whole wedge minus the part I do not want to have:
$$\int_0^v \int^z_{g(z)} f(z,y) d y d z - \int_0^{g(v)} \int^z_{g(z)} f(z,y) d y d z$$
Because $g(v)$ is a constant the second part can be solved just like the first term.
Looking at the area and following the discussion with MickG above:
\begin{align}
\int_0^v \int^z_{g(z)} f(z,y) d y d z = \int_0^v \int_y^{\min \{g^{-1}(y),v\}} f(z,y) d z d y \\
= \int_0^{g(v)} \int_y^{g^{-1}(y)} f(z,y) d z d y + \int^v_{g(v)} \int_y^v f(z,y) d z d y.
\end{align}
Redo for the second part (just exchange $g(v)$ and $v$) and take the difference.